# Draggable NSView returns to origin on mouseUp or when movement stops

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, draggable, nsview

I'm new to Cocoa development on the Mac, and I'm having issues creating a draggable NSView subclass, despite having followed many different guides, including [the main Apple docs on custom views](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MouseTrackingEvents/MouseTrackingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH11-SW6).

The code I've implemented so far is:

```objc
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *) e {
    [[NSCursor closedHandCursor] push];
    self.lastDragLocation = [e locationInWindow];
}

-(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSView* superView = [self superview];
    NSPoint currentOrigin = self.lastDragLocation;
    NSRect currentFrame = [self frame];
    NSPoint nextOrigin = NSMakePoint(currentOrigin.x + [event deltaX],
                                     currentOrigin.y + ([event deltaY] * 
                                          ([superView isFlipped] ? 1 : -1))
                                     );
    [self setFrameOrigin:nextOrigin];
    [self autoscroll:event];
    [superView setNeedsDisplayInRect:NSUnionRect(currentFrame, [self frame])];

    self.lastDragLocation = nextOrigin;
}

-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent*)event {
    [NSCursor pop];
    [[self window] invalidateCursorRectsForView:self];
}
```

Everything seems to work when I drag the view, but when I stop moving or release the mouse, the view snaps back to the original origin. When this happens during a drag, subsequent drag events set the view back to the right place, only to repeat the issue.

Incidentally, this is XCode 5.0 running on Mountain Lion.

Comment: Are there any Autolayout constraints set on the view you're dragging? I was having a similar problem where I tried to move a view programmatically and Autolayout would snap it back to its original location. if this is the case, try subclassing the view and override `- (void)resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:(NSSize)oldSize {};` like that to do nothing.

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner; I had worked around this solution by creating the views programmatically (the xib-based ones were temporary), but I didn't know *why* this fixed my issue until I read your comment.